JetPack Compose - ModalBottomSheet is not updating
JetPack Compose Bottom Sheet is not updated:
data on bottomSheet is not updated after updating the stateFlow
i have a mutable state object that gets updated from the bottom sheet through viewmodel, but after updating the object the changes don't get reflected on the bottom sheet modal
below is the code (not Completed) but gives idea on the issue
here is the main screen where the bottom sheet is called
 var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
  if (showBottomSheet) {
                ModalBottomSheet(
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        showBottomSheet = false
                    },
                    sheetState = sheetState
                ) {
                    myObject(viewModel)
                    Button(onClick = {
                        scope.launch { sheetState.hide() }.invokeOnCompletion {
                            if (!sheetState.isVisible) {
                                showBottomSheet = false
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Hide bottom sheet")
                    }
                }
            }


Here is where the bottomsheet content
@Composable
fun myObject(viewModel: ViewModel){
    val mutableObjects by taskListviewModel.mutableMainObjects.collectAsState()

 for (item in mutableObjects)
        TaskScreen(item,taskListviewModel)

}


@Composable
fun TaskScreen(models:ArrayList<Model>,viewModel: ViewModel){
   
    Row (
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween){
for (item in models){
    ElevatedFilterChip(selected = item.isSelected, onClick = {viewModel.update(item, isSelected = !item.isSelected)
       
    }, label = { Text(item.label!!) }, leadingIcon = {
        if (item.isSelected){ Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Done,
            contentDescription = "Selected"
        )}
    })
}

the viewModel where data gets updated
class ViewModel:ViewModel{
 val _mutableMainObjects = MutableStateFlow(ArrayList<ArrayList<Model>>())
 val mutableMainObjects =_mutableFilterMainObjects.asStateFlow()

update(model:Model,isSelected:Boolean){

newObject.isSelected=isSelected
.
.
_mutableMainObjects= newObject
}



There are some pieces missing in the code you posted. Where is taskListviewModel coming from? Where is newObject coming from? Please edit your post to include this missing pieces. Also include your full update method of your ViewModel.
